# How to run and stop an infinite loop in a python thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to run a (series of) infinite loops that must be able to check an externally set condition to terminate. I thought the threading module would allow that, but my efforts so fare have failed. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
import threading

class Looping(object):

    def __init__(self):
     self.isRunning = True

    def runForever(self):
       while self.isRunning == True:
          "do stuff here"

l = Looping()
t = threading.Thread(target = l.runForever())
t.start()
l.isRunning = False
```

I would have expected t.start to run in a separate thread, with  l's attributes still accessible. This is not what happens. I tried the snippet above in the python shell (IPython). Execution of t start immediately after instantiation and it blocks any further input.
There is obviously something I am not getting right about the threading module.
Any suggestion on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are calling `runForever` too early.  Use `target = l.runForever` without parentheses.

A function call is not evaluated until after its arguments are.  When you write `runforever()`, it calls the function right then, before even creating the thread.  By just passing `runForever`, you pass the function object itself, which the threading apparatus can then call when it is ready.  The point is that *you* don't actually want to call `runForever`; you just want to tell the threading code that `runForever` is what *it* should call later.

Comment: Ah, the parens. They still trip me up (My experience with python is less than a month old). Thanks